# Logging Task Ids from ActiveMQ broker to the client application

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I am running ActiveMQ 5.15.5 as a standalone broker and my spring application 
is connecting to it. 
I wanted to know if I can log the Task-ID that the broker logs, in the 
client application logs.

Currently application logs look like:

```
INFO ] 2018-11-29 09:52:19,144 [ActiveMQ Session Task] .... 
[INFO ] 2018-11-29 09:52:19,168 [ActiveMQ Session Task] ... 
[INFO ] 2018-11-29 09:52:19,199 [ActiveMQ Session Task] ....
```

I believe if I had embedded activeMQ the logs would look like

```
INFO ] 2018-11-29 09:52:19,144 [ActiveMQ Session Task-9] .... 
[INFO ] 2018-11-29 09:52:19,168 [ActiveMQ Session Task-9] ...
```

Looking at the client application logs, i do not have a way to categorize 
transactions by multiple users as they are all logged as "ActiveMQ Session 
Task"

Is there a way to log the Task-ID from broker (I do see the Task-ID at the 
broker logs activemq.log) in the client logs. 
I tried to set the ActiveMQ logs in the client log4j.xml to info with no 
luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Task-ID", as you call it, which is logged here is actually just the name of the thread on the broker which is performing the work. The client has no idea about the thread name on the broker and there is no way to communicate that information with the client. Those threads are pooled and re-used over & over so using their names to identify a unique transaction almost certainly wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: So is there a way to identify or group the transactions for one message at the client end. Because currently I have hundreds of messages being processed concurrently and no way to debug incase of an issue with one of them.

Comment: This is a completely different question than the one you actually wrote. I recommend you ask a new question and explain exactly what you're trying to do, what API you're using on the client to do your transaction work, what you've tried so far, and why it hasn't worked.